# How to print screen view on iPhone?

Tags: ios, printing, screenshot

I have an a button named printscreen in a nib. In my .m file, I have -(IBAction)printscreen {}.

What should go in between the {} so that when I click my button, the screenshot is printed. I don't want the image saved, and I don't want it going to files and all that nonsense. I want to click the button, and as soon as I click it, it should print whatever is on the current screen.

I've gone through all the questions and none were very useful. I'm just looking for code here. Please help out.

Comment: Print using the iPhone's built-in printer?

Comment: You don't get it. I don't want to go through the conventional process of taking a screenshot, and then going to the saved pictures file in the gallery and then clicking it. I want to print the screen from one click on my own app itself. It should be like this: I click the button and it prints immediately whatever was on the screen whenever I clicked the button.

Comment: But print how? AirPrint? Or what?

Comment: Airprint, naturally. So now that you know, would you like to shed some insight?

Comment: This is several questions, and you should do some research before posting here. There are plenty of resources available on getting a screenshot, and printing with AirPrint.

Answer (score 5):

You can get an UIImage representation of the screenshot using something like this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.window.bounds.size);
[view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then you can do anything with it; maybe you want to write it to the Photo Library:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, NULL, NULL);
```

As far as I'm concerned, immediate programmatical AirPrint printing is not implemented, you always have to go through the [`UIPrintInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/iPad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.